# Sass error : Invalid CSS after "typography-config" angular 4.x

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

I want to integrate my custom fonts for my angular 4.x project which are in assets folder. and I am using angular material. so for material I am setting custom typography in my styles.sass

Here's the code:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming'

$used-fonts : 'Avenir', arial

$general-typography : mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: quote($used-fonts)
)

@include mat-core($general-typography)
```

The error which I got:

```
Invalid CSS after "...ography-config(": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{"
```

giving me an error at `:`

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to compile a minimal SCSS file that only contains the styles you have shown? The reason I ask is because the compiler might actually be complaining about an error that occurs earlier in the stylesheet.

Comment: yeah got the same error with sassmeister online.

Comment: It's not because you've left out semicolons is it? e.g. try adding semicolons at the end of each delaration: @import '~@angular/material/theming';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest You should try within one line. it will consider it as nested value

```
$general-typography : mat-typography-config($font-family: quote($used-fonts))
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to try adding semicolons after each declaration. CSS requires a semicolon after each declaration except the last declaration in a rule (which is optional), and I think SASS follows suit.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$used-fonts : 'Avenir', arial;

$general-typography : mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: quote($used-fonts)
);

@include mat-core($general-typography);
```